# Playing Video for Splash screens etc using Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, video

I've been searching around on internet a way to display a video using XNA/Monogame. But everything tend to go in the direction of the class Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Media.Video. Unfortunatly, my xna Framework does not contain any Video member in the Media namespace as shown below. Also i've found this [stackhex question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48452/playing-video-in-monogame) which is the same question but the answer contains a gist with the code that does not exists anymore, so i'm a bit stuck here.

[image]

i'll appriciate any help, thank you for your time

---

After the recommandations of @Steven, i've tried to see what visual studio give me for replacement, What i've ended up with is the Video Class turning into the enum VideoSoundtrackType which is not a video or video player class.

[image]

```
public SplashScreenScene(GraphicsDevice gd, ContentManager contentManager, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{

   GraphicsDevice = gd;
   ContentManager = contentManager;
   SpriteBatch = spriteBatch;

   SplashScreenTexture2DAnimation = new NonRepeatingTexture2DAnimation();

   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Content/Animations/SplashScreenAnimationMetadata.xml"));

   SplashScreenTexture2DAnimation.LoadAnimation(xmlDoc, contentManager);
   DisplayOffsetMatrix = new OrthographicCamera(gd).GetViewMatrix();

   var Video = new VideoSoundtrackType();

}
```

here is the enum from meta data

[image]

NB: for the moment i've created a class that holds texture2Ds to make an animation. But if I want to create cinematics it will be a bit difficult (or i can create simple story telling through images and text like undertale and other did).

Comment: Else i can do an image sequence an display them one by one with the sprite batch as Sega did this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-aQvP7CUAI) but it's not really modern to do it and it is a bit an inconvinient way of animating (and works only with twwo colors)

Comment: Sometimes these usings may not work directly, have you tried right-clicking the Video and clicked on 'Quick Resolve' or 'Quick actions and refactoring', and add the using that way?

Comment: the replacement that visual studio gives is an enum which can't be used as what i want

Comment: Please share your code as text, not as images.

Comment: You might want to double check the target platform of the Monogame binaries you're using, as they might not be built with the full Media library for that platform.I know the OpenGL version of Monogame had this as an issue several years back.

Comment: Just checked the Monogame source code, the OpenGL Monogame library currently doesn't appear to include the Video/Videoplayer classes, so if you're using the OpenGL version this is probably why.

Comment: I have created the project jusing the Monogame CrossPlatform model, it might be Under the OpenGL instance of monogame since it is made for Windows, mac and linux, OpenGL being a standard Library it wont be surprising if it's the case. i'll share the code as text @DMGregory

Comment: i've found this https://github.com/hozuki/MonoGame.Extended2/tree/master/Sources/MonoGame.Extended.VideoPlayback, might help since i'm using monogame.extended

Comment: apparently, this Library contains a video.cs class : https://github.com/hozuki/MonoGame.Extended2/tree/master/Sources/MonoGame.Extended.VideoPlayback/Media

Comment: I had a thought, is it possible to parse video files into a List<Texture2D> without having to pass through the video class that is missing in OpenGL ?

Comment: 16 images animations works fine, I'll be using them instead but I keep open this thread

Comment: I've found this Library, i'll do testing https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp/